# Enter character in MongoDB in Azure Cosmos DB collection. How can I remove the collection?

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm not able to remove a collection because I managed to add an Enter character in the name somehow.

Here is the URL I found with Fiddler while trying to delete the collection via PowerShell with `Remove-AzCosmosDBMongoDBCollection`:

```
DELETE /subscriptions/ad5b32b4-1023-4e0a-bc65-fc09541cf7df/resourceGroups/RG-WORK-02/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/work-mongodb-02/mongodbDatabases/WORK/collections/%2Fsubscriptions%2Fad5b32b4-1023-4e0a-bc65-fc09541cf7df%2FresourceGroups%2FRG-WORK-02%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.DocumentDB%2FdatabaseAccounts%2Fwork-mongodb-02%2FmongodbDatabases%2FWORK%2Fcollections%2Fjustatest%0A?api-version=2021-04-15 HTTP/1.1
```

`%0A` is an enter character for an URL.

I've tried all kind of things

- Adding the escape characters r n, n and r separated with the name in PowerShell.
- I tried it by first calling the collection & then removing it..
- I tried it through ATLAS Compass by copying the special character
- The portal of course by copying all kinds of things (unsuccessful).

I cannot create a support ticket because it's an MSDN environment.
Does anyone else have an idea or an incredible creative idea?

Comment: I assume deleting the whole account is not an option? Otherwise you should be able to create tickets for such cases AFAIK. Just try it in the portal, I can create tickets for my MSDN stuff. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot..
Yes that's a way as well, but I also wanted to know what I can do without deleting it ;-)